# How to stop Gmail from clipping or trimming email in the middle of an HTML element

Tags: html, email, gmail

I understand that Gmail has a hard 102kb limit on emails, at which point it will clip or trim the email, showing the "View entire message" button.

This in itself is not a problem for me, however in my case it seems that thee clip is occuring right in the middle of a  opening tag, which is leaving it to show as plain text at the bottom of the email - not ideal.

I haven't seen any other cases of this, so am wondering if anyone else has encountered this issue and knows how to solve it?

Note: Reducing the size of the email to less than 102kb is not an option. I don't mind the clipping but would like it to cut off before beginning an html element, rather than right in the middle

Comment: I'd suggest asking this question on the Email Geeks slack channel - https://email.geeks.chat/